# Can't inflate custom background editText

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set background in my EditText.
I found and copy from internet this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:color="#028b53"
        android:width="2.5dp" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#c3c3c3"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

and set this in EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRandom"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="168dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tRandom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tRandom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tRandom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.761" />
```

now after run app I get crash:

```
drawable/edittext" (7f060054) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060054 a=-1 r=0x7f060054}
```

How to fix that ?

[image: v24]

Comment: Is your background names edittext.xml?

Comment: How did you call your background xml?

Comment: he is "edittext.xml" but he have also (v24)

Comment: why are you complicating your own life mate? Just name it something very explicit like edit_text_background.xml or whatever.

Comment: change name of xml no helps

Comment: try to put the edittext.xml in drawable it self not in drawable-v24

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery check my screen, I haven't this in v24 folder, just AndroidStudio make a information

Comment: but when android studio do this it means that this file is in v24 folder ...you can change that file location by accessing the res folder in the file explorer then cut that file from drawable-v24 to drawable...note that you can access the project in file explorer by right click "on drawable in the image above" then click on show in explorer

Comment: Is it safe ? why did not it find in the right folder right away?